# Right syntaxis for add trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, triggers

Code:

```
# Triggers for table Likes->News

CREATE TRIGGER `TriggerUpdateNewsAfterInsertLikes` AFTER INSERT ON `Likes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
UPDATE `News` SET 
`CountUpLikes` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = NEW.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'up'),
`CountDownLikes` = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = NEW.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'down'),
`CountFavorites` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = NEW.`NewsIdn` AND `IsFavorite` = 'yes');
END;
```

When i want add it trigger in phpmyadmin i get error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near '*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = NEW.`NewsIdn` 
AND `Type` = 'down'),
`CountFav' at line 8
```

If i use `id` instead `*` i get error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near '' at line 9
```

Tell me please how right add it trigger?

Answer (score 1):

As unbelievable as it sounds, in mysql you can't have a space between `count` and `(*)`:

```
select count(*) -- OK
select count (*) -- syntax error!
```

In your case, it's in the second subquery. Change it to:

```
...
`CountDownLikes` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = NEW.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'down'),
...
```

---

The same applies to `cast(...)`, this is a syntax error: `cast (col as unsigned)` (note the space between`cast`and `(`). I can tell you I wasted about a hour hunting that little gem down.

---

#### Edit;

The other error is probably due to not changing the delimiter, which is needed if you have semicolons within the procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `TriggerUpdateNewsAfterInsertLikes` AFTER INSERT ON `Likes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
UPDATE `News` SET 
`CountUpLikes` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = NEW.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'up'),
`CountDownLikes` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = NEW.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'down'),
`CountFavorites` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = NEW.`NewsIdn` AND `IsFavorite` = 'yes');
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: oh, sorry, i dont see it, i think that error in `*` or `''`. big thanks and sorry.

Comment: now i get second error(`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9 `). see code please http://pastebin.com/gSr70eci

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `TriggerUpdateNewsAfterInsertLikes` AFTER INSERT ON `Likes`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE `News` SET 
`CountUpLikes` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = NEW.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'up'),
`CountDownLikes` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = NEW.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'down'),
`CountFavorites` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = NEW.`NewsIdn` AND `IsFavorite` = 'yes');
END
```